# Using JDK 7 Or Higher With Android Studio And Eclipse On Mac OSX

Tags: java, eclipse, android-studio, osx-mavericks, java-8

Both Android Studio and Eclipse are asking me to install JDK 6 even though JDK 8 is already installed. Several workarounds online told me change the java_home to point the JDK 8 installation location, done that such that both /usr/libexec/java_home and java -version commands refer to the JDK 8 installation but Android Studio and Eclipse still asking me to install JDK 6. Anyone solved this issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Android Studio is based on **Intellij Idea 13**. The solution [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23455956-Selecting-the-JDK-version-the-IDE-will-run-under) also applies. Just modifying Info.plist from *1.6** to *1.7** did it for me.

Btw, I've observed that at least Android Studio 0.5.5 uses massive amounts of memory. With Java 8 it gets over 2GB for very simple projects. With Java 7 it is still bad, but takes around 1.5GB.

Comment: thanks very much. been trying all kinds of workarounds all week. had to reinstall mavericks at one point because i'd messed up the jdk installation files so bad. thanks again.

Comment: @user1906 so taking into account that it uses massive amounts of memory with Java 7 and 8, would you recommend to switch to Jdk6 for speed?

Comment: @DimitryK, I've been using the latest versions of Android Studio with Java 7 and the memory usage has improved. I've kept using Java 7.

Comment: @user1906 thank you! I will try to use it now with Java `(build 1.8.0-b132)` on Ubuntu1204 and maybe later may try to fall back to java7 so see the difference. So far works ok.

Comment: You can't modify any file in Android Studio directory in newer versions, because the checksum is being checked. Is there another way to fix this?

Comment: @MichałKisiel, I downloaded one of the -rc versions recently and it worked after modifying the Info.plist file.

Comment: @user1906 Yes, but you won't be able to update Android Studio now.

Comment: @MichałKisiel, I just upgraded 1.0 to 1.0.1 without issue. I got a message about replacing the file, and that was it. I'm still on 10.8, I'm not sure if this works different on 10.9 or 10.10.

Comment: You can just add the new version without removing the old ones, by separating versions with a comma.
<key>JVMVersion</key>
<string>1.6*,1.7+,1.8+</string>

Answer (score 3):

Changing SDK Location also works for Android Studio Project

[image]

[image]